# How do you require Active Model Associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activemodel

I'm trying to use Active Model Associations without Rails...how do I require it?

```
require 'active_model'
require 'activemodel-associations'

class Base
  include ActiveModel::Model
  include ActiveModel::Associations

end
```

```
 `require': cannot load such file -- activemodel-associations
```

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/joker1007/activemodel-associations?

Comment: I am interested in hearing more about why.

Comment: Why? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to model my domain using PORO without standing up a database